# Subtraction of Counter objects with negative values included in result

Tags: python-3.x, counter

I was trying to subtract two counter objects in a way that zero and negative values are included in the resultant counter but wasn't getting the desired output. The sample block of code
'`

```
1- dic = {'1':6 , '2':4 , '3':2}
2- dic2 = {'1':3 , '2':1 , '3':5}
3- obj1 = Counter(dic)
4- obj2 = Counter(dic2)
5- obj = obj1-obj2 
6- print(obj) 
#Output
Counter({'1':3 , '2':3}) #it omits the '3':-3 part

#In line 5 I also used subtract() but it is returning none 
5 - obj = obj1.subtract(obj2)
#output
None
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Subtraction of Counter by `obj1 - obj2` only keep positive counts and return the Counter, while `obj1.subtract(obj2)` keep negative counts but it changes `obj1` in-place and return `None`.

Therefore, you are assigning `obj` to `None`, you can find that `obj1` is actually subtracted.

```
obj1 = Counter({'1':6, '2':4, '3':2})
obj2 = Counter({'1':3, '2':1, '3':5})
obj = obj1.subtract(obj2)
print(obj)
print(obj1)
```

Output:

```
None
Counter({'1': 3, '2': 3, '3': -3})
```

You can just remove the assignment and `print(obj1)`, or make a copy first if you want to keep `obj1`.

```
# 1. change obj1
obj1.subtract(obj2)
print(obj1)
# 2. keep obj1
obj = obj1.copy()
obj.subtract(obj2)
print(obj)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [**`subtract`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.subtract) method of `Counter` for this.

```
In [23]: c = Counter(a=4, b=2, c=0, d=-2)
    ...: d = Counter(a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4)
    ...: c.subtract(d)
    ...: c
Out[23]: Counter({'a': 3, 'b': 0, 'c': -3, 'd': -6})
```

---

**Note:** `Counter('abbbc') - Counter('bccd')` also Subtract count, but keep only results with positive counts.

Comment: Actually i am creating counter objects by using dictionary henceforth when i use subtract() it returns 'None'.

Comment: @Abhist this should work `obj1.subtract(obj2)`